# optimal control: how to build a good mathematical foundation

Tags: optimal-control

I am a PhD student in electrical engineering and need to work on Optimal control theory. Whenever I go through theorems, I see mathematical basics that I don't know (like optimization and theorems about hyper-planes and manifolds). Can you please suggest me readings that can help me build the mathematical foundation for this field?

Answer (score 0):

As a start, you can brush up your knowledge by studying some undergraduate mathematic texts on real analysis, topology, and optimization.

Some books I found useful initially:

Browder, Andrew (1996). Mathematical Analysis: An Introduction.

Tu, Loring (2010). An Introduction to Manifolds.

Chong and Zak (2013). An Introduction to Optimization.